# Is there a way to use a a4j:commandButton without generating type=submit?

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces

I have 2 buttons:

```
                        <a4j:commandButton
                            execute="@this"
                            value="clear"
                            immediate="true"
                            render=":thisForm :anotherForm"
                            action="#{myMB.clearFields}" />

                        <a4j:commandButton
                            value="execute"
                            type="submit"
                            action="#{myMB.executeAction}"
                            render=":anotherForm" />
```

And both are generating inputs with type="submit". But I would like the  key to execute the second button. Is there a way to change the type for the first button?

Comment: 'the key' being?

Comment: and you can always switch them in the xhtml

Comment: @Kukeltje my workaround was switch them and invert direction to rtl on css. But I didn't like it...

Comment: sometimes (especially with an older abandoned component suite like richfaces) it is the only think I can help with... Sorry... and keep in mind that 'executing the first button that is encountered when pressing enter' is **default HTML behaviour**, not something that JSF does! So maybe you could have added some javascript key/enter handling but I assume you would not have liked that either then.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a4j:commandButton
    type="button" .../>
```

on the first button should do the trick.

> **type** - Type of button to create. Can be one of "submit", "button", "image" and "reset". If not specified, the default value is "submit".

Refer to [component reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/index.html?a4j/commandButton.html) for more details.

Comment: But iirc you cannot execute an action on this `type=button` (you can't with plain jsf or primefaces) so while it might 'solve the basic problem in the question it won't result in a fully working solution (again, iirc)

Comment: @Kukeltje did you try it? type="button" does not prevent action to be invoked.

Comment: I stated 'if I remember correctly', so no I did not try in Richfaces (is over 8 years ago I used it) I tried in modern plain JSF and modern PrimeFaces and there the action  is not called, so hence my remark. But great it works here! Upvoted...